# How many surfaces is reasonable?

Tags: python, performance, pygame, pygame-surface

How many instances of `pygame.Surface` is it reasonable to use simultaneously?

More precisely, how costly is it to:

- Hold a surface in memory?
- Blit a surface onto another?

Consequently, how many surfaces can be kept in a list (or any other container), and how many surfaces can be blitted at every frame, with respect for other operations related to the application?

---

Since this might be too broad, here is a concrete situation. I want to make an animated background, with repeating patterns. I want every element of the pattern to move independently, so I use one surface for each of them.

If I want to display one hundred elements, is it still acceptable to use one surface per element?

Comment: You should try and observe the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made games that have had arrays with over ten thousand surfaces in it.  It ran just fine.  You shouldn't be afraid to use a lot of surfaces, go crazy.

If you've ever seen the game Don't Starve, I was making a game similar to it.  I had fifteen different biomes, and I had multiple ground tiles for each biome for variation.  That alone pushed it over 100 surfaces.  I then had a bunch of different plants, like trees, berry bushes, carnivorous happyplants, etc.  There was a large variety of these, and you could have a hundred of them loaded at one time in some locations.  Again, each of these had variations.  I also had many moving entities, like giant spiders and stuff like that.  Some types of entities required over a hundred surfaces, just for all the animations that might occur from their variety of possible actions.

All in all, I probably had a maximum of a thousand surfaces being displayed at one time, and over twenty thousand loaded.  The game worked just fine, and it would even run at 60 fps; but not without the extensive use of threads, as expected.

The conclusion:  Assume there is no limit, because there may as well not be any.